# Alternative to Apache River?

Tags: java, rmi

I have been asked to work on Apache River for a company project. After bit of reading and running the examples, I realized this is an old technology. I want to know what is the 2019 alternative to Apache River? If this question is relevant to anyone please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I would use AMQP Or SOAP. Would prefer AMQP.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any comment on why do you prefer AMQP the most?